# How to decrease space between input text fields of form in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am very new to bootstrap. I am creating a form using bootstrap. I need to decrease the space between two input text fields.

My Code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="addKPITODB">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI
            Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputEmail3"
                placeholder="KPI Name" name="kpi_name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">KPI
            SQL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="K sql"
                name="kpi_sql">
        </div>
    </div></form>
```

I am getting the below output for this.
[image]

As I have marked in the above image I need to decrease the space between two input text fields.

Please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: change property of `form-group` default is `.form-group { margin-bottom: 15px;}`

Comment: I tried this. Space is decreasing but it is affecting alignment of  a form.

Comment: I tried this. Space is decreasing but it is affecting alignment of  a form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Because following css is applied in `bootstrap.min.css`

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

To Decrease space you should use following css.

```
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwweg0b6/)

Comment: Thanks for your time. Where to include this. Please help. Whether I have to create a separate css or I should include this in head section of my html page.?? Please tell me.

Comment: @Abdul You can Add in head section between style tag `<style> </style>`. And also you create  separate css.

Comment: @Abdul But add this css below the bootstrap css.

Comment: Thank you I have placed the above code in head section of my html page. It is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use this css to reduce space

```
.form-group
   {
      margin-bottom: 10px !important; /* change it as per your requirment */
    }
```